# Controlar reproducción de videos generados dinámicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, handlebars.js

Tengo una serie de cards, que al ser clickeadas muestran un modal con un video. Esta información proviene de un JSON y está enlazada mediante handlebars. 
El problema radica en que los videos se siguen reproduciendo aún cuando se cierra el modal. Mi intención es controlar eso mediante la API de YouTube (que ya está en mi sitio, ya que controla otros dos videos estáticos). 
No estoy usando Bootstrap. Sí jQuery.

**HTML**

```
<script id="card-partial" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <figure class="card">
        <div class="img-container img-toggler" id="{{ga_img}}">
            <img src="assets/img/tips/{{image}}" alt="">
        </div>
        <figcaption>
            <p>
                {{text}}
            </p>
            <div class="social-container">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://<?php echo $server_host ?>/tips/{{id}}" target="_blank" class="fa fa-facebook" id="{{ga_facebook}}"></a>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text={{text}}&url=http://<?php echo $server_host ?>/tips/{{id}}" target="_blank" class="fa fa-twitter" id="{{ga_twitter}}"></a>
            </div>
        </figcaption>
        <div class="card-modal">
            <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
            {{#if youtube_id}}
                <div class="video-embedder" id="tip-video">
                    <iframe width="560" height="349" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{youtube_id}}" frameborder="0" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
                {{else}}
                    <img src="assets/img/tips/{{image_mob}}" class="hide-for-large" alt="">
                    <img src="assets/img/tips/{{image_desk}}" class="show-for-large" alt="">
            {{/if}}
        </div>
    </figure>
</script>
```

**JS**

```
(function(window) {

    function toggleCardModal() {

        $('.img-toggler').each(function(index) {
            var $this = $(this);
            var $modal = $this.siblings('.card-modal');

            $this.click(function() {
                var itemPosition = $(window).scrollTop() + 'px';
                $modal.addClass('open').css('top', itemPosition);
                $('main').addClass('canvas-open');
            })

            $modal.find('.fa-close').click(function() {
                console.log(player3)
                player3.stopVideo();
                $modal.removeClass('open');
                $('main').removeClass('canvas-open');
            })
        });
    }

    window.toggleCardModal = toggleCardModal;
}(window));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para parar el reproductor de **youtube** puedes utilizar el siguiente fragmento:

```
$('.video-embedder iframe')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'pauseVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
```

Entonces agregando eso dentro de la función del click en `.fa-close` quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
(function(window) {

    function toggleCardModal() {

        $('.img-toggler').each(function(index) {
            var $this = $(this);
            var $modal = $this.siblings('.card-modal');

            $this.click(function() {
                var itemPosition = $(window).scrollTop() + 'px';
                $modal.addClass('open').css('top', itemPosition);
                $('main').addClass('canvas-open');
            })

            $modal.find('.fa-close').click(function() {
                $(this).parent().find('.video-embedder iframe')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'pauseVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
                $modal.removeClass('open');
                $('main').removeClass('canvas-open');
            })
        });
    }

    window.toggleCardModal = toggleCardModal;
}(window));
```

---

#### Nota

Esta solución es la que existe por ahora pero a lo largo de los años fue cambiando de diferentes formas a cómo se puede pausar un video en youtube.

---

#### Ejemplo de `play`, `pause` y `stop`

[Acá te dejo un jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kxzwxmwb/) en el que podes ver cómo hacer estos tres casos de reproducir, pausar y parar un video con **Youtube API**.

Comment: Excelente! Era eso precisamente lo que buscaba. Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Comenzó funcionando esta solución, pero ahora ya no funciona. Bastante raro realmente. En la consola me da el siguiente error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of undefined`.

Comment: Se lo estás pasando como variable o como `string` el `postMessage`?

Comment: Perdón, yo sólo agregué la línea de código que me sugeriste. Tenía que agregar el `postMessage` en otro lado?

Comment: Perdón, leí mal. Ya sé cuál es el error, no puse el `iframe` en el selector, ahí modifico la respuesta.

Comment: Ahora si! Muchas gracias!